# Return array including plus / minus range of an input integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

```
a = np.array(5)

result = np.array([a-2, a-1, a, a+1, a+2])

print result
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

correct!

But what would be a better way to get this with out manually writing `+- 2 a-2, a-1, a, a+1, a+2`

EDIT: second problem:

```
a = np.array([5,16,27])
res = np.concatenate([a-2, a-1, a, a+1, a+2])
print res
array([ 3, 14, 25,  4, 15, 26,  5, 16, 27,  6, 17, 28,  7, 18, 29])
```

Ok

but how to do this with out writing `+-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)?

```
np.arange(a-2, a+3)
#=> array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Note that I had to use a+3 for the upper bound since the arguments specify a half-open interval.

**Update** One possible solution for the updated question:

```
np.transpose([np.arange(n-2, n+3) for n in a]).flatten()
#=> array([ 3, 14, 25,  4, 15, 26,  5, 16, 27,  6, 17, 28,  7, 18, 29])
```

As a function:

```
def ranges(a, x):
  return np.transpose([np.arange(n-x, n+x+1) for n in a]).flatten()
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if `a = np.array([5,6,7])`. I want to get +- for each element

Comment: @jean I added a possible solution for you. Note that this is not trying to be the most efficient, but readable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider this method ?

```
result = [a+i for i in range(-2,3)]
```

for the second problem, just use a loop (using my method)

```
a, result = np.array([5,6,7]), []
for k in a: result.append([k+i for i in range(-2,3)])
```

or

```
results = [k+i for k in a for i in range(-2,3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `numpy`, take advantage of its vectorisation.

You can also wrap your logic in a function to make it adaptable.

**Problem 1**

```
a = np.array(5)

def ranger(a, n):
    return np.arange(a-n, a+n+1)

ranger(a, 2)  # array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

**Problem 2**

```
a = np.array([5, 16, 27])

def ranger(a, n):
    return np.hstack([a+i for i in range(-n, n+1)])

ranger(a, 2)  # array([ 3, 14, 25,  4, 15, 26,  5, 16, 27,  6, 17, 28,  7, 18, 29])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.add.outer(np.r_[-2:3], [5,16,27]).ravel()
array([ 3, 14, 25,  4, 15, 26,  5, 16, 27,  6, 17, 28,  7, 18, 29])
```

Comment: @jean Fair enough ;-)